# TryCast to Double?

Tags: vb.net, casting

I am trying to cast a string to double, but I don't want it to throw exception, but to return some value. I found the TryCast function but it seems I am not using it right. I try `TryCast(string, Double)` and it says that "Double" is a value type, not a reference type. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's a *conversion* not a *cast*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Double.TryParse(string, double)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) method instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
If Double.TryParse(value, New Double) Then
    ' TODO
end if
```